# CSS inside PHP code messes up layout in IE9

Tags: php, javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

I am designing a website that will have users. Depending on the SESSION, homepage will either show "Log in" or "Log out" buttons. I try to do it with following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {

?>
<style>

    #login {display: none;}
    #logout {display: block;}

</style>
<?

} else {

?>
<style>

    #logout {display: none;}
    #login {display: block;}

</style>
<?

}
```

?>

Everything works perfect in all browsers except IE9; in IE layout messes up, images don't show up, their sizes change, etc. What other code can I use? I can use any suggestions, maybe even javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you apply this condition to the html instead of css

Comment: Instead, why not wrap the actual HTML elements in the if statements?

Comment: Is it displaying in Quirks mode?  If so, it is because you have output before you declare the HTML doc type.

Comment: @Mayank swami and @Jeemusu; thank you both, I just copied the above code inside HTML tags and it worked. Previously it was at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments above I solved the problem by copying the above code (except `session_start()`) inside the 'html' tags (specifically inside the 'body' tags). Previously that code was at the beginning of the file, outside the 'html' tags.

Comment: so from an invalid position to a valid one - no surprised that worked :-)